# Выбор всех тэгов, создаваемых при клике на класс

Tags: jquery, javascript, html, php

Здравствуйте, уважаемые коллеги, у меня к вам такой нелегкий вопрос. Я сделал запрос на сервер таким способом

```
$(".click_top").click(function () {
    window.topid = $(this).attr("topid");
    window.semestr = $(this).attr("semestr");
    window.kurs = $(this).attr("kurs");
    $.post( <? php echo '"'.base_url(); ?> ofis_reg / dekanat / itogxml ", {fm_id: fm_id,top_id: topid,kurs: kurs,semestr: semestr},
    function (xml){
        $(".bg_ul ").html("");
        $(xml).find('pred').each(function() {
            pred_name = $(this).find('pred_name').text();
            pred_id = $(this).find('pred_id').text();
            $(".bg_ul ").append('<li value="'+pred_id+'">'+pred_name+'</li>');
        });
    });
});
```

Вот html

```
<ul class="bg_ul"></ul>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="bleft click_top"  topid="<?php echo $toptar[$i]["top_id"]?>" kurs="<?php echo $toptar[$i]["kurs"]?>" semestr="<?php echo $toptar[$i]["semestr"]?>"><?php echo $toptar[$i]["top_name"]?></td>
        <td align="center" class="click_top" topid="<?php echo $toptar[$i]["top_id"]?>" kurs="<?php echo $toptar[$i]["kurs"]?>" semestr="<?php echo $toptar[$i]["semestr"]?>"><?php echo $toptar[$i]["kurs"]?></td>
        <td align="center" class="click_top" topid="<?php echo $toptar[$i]["top_id"]?>" kurs="<?php echo $toptar[$i]["kurs"]?>" semestr="<?php echo $toptar[$i]["semestr"]?>"><?php echo $toptar[$i]["semestr"]?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Задача в том, что надо выбрать все теги `<li>`, которые генерируются при клике на класс `click_top`.

```
<ul class="bg_ul">
</ul>
```

Мой метод

```
$('.bg_ul>li').click(function(){
    alert("OK");
});
```

не работает и почему? Если я не генерирую эти теги `<li>`, а просто вставлю их в html, то работает нормально?

Answer (score 1):

Событие не подхватывается для динамически созданных элементов, используйте

```
.live('click', function(){})
```

**update:** способ действительно легкий и простой, но обратите внимание на ответ [@zippp](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/4536/zippp), он обьяснил суть возникновения такой проблемы и предложил навешивать событие на элементы непосредственно при их создании. Единственно, в коде который он предложил событие навешивается не на `<li> а на <ul>  - $('< ul>').attr('class','bg_ul').click()`, может поэтому что-то не работало. мне кажется, что лучше использовать его подход, но только подправить код

```
function (xml){
        var bg_ul = $(".bg_ul ").html("");
        $(xml).find('pred').each(function() {
            pred_name = $(this).find('pred_name').text();
            pred_id = $(this).find('pred_id').text();
            var bg_ul_li = $('<li value="'+pred_id+'">'+pred_name+'</li>')
            .click(function(){alert('ok')});
    $(".bg_ul ").append(bg_ul_li);
        }
```

Comment: Или хватит юзать jquery ^^

Comment: самый легкий способ спасиба makregistr!

Comment: присмотритесь к ответу @zippp, я обновил свой ответ с учетом предложенного им кода

Answer (score 1):

Ваш код, видимо, работает по событию `$(document).ready()`, в этот момент и вешаются все обработки ивентов на элементы страницы. Соответственно, если элемента еще нет, не на что вешать реакцию на клик. А в тот момент, когда вы сгенерировали элемент, никакая функция, которая вешает эту обработку клика, не запускается. Т.е. вам или сразу нужно генерировать элементы с обработкой, типа так, если по-простенькому

```
$('< ul>').attr('class','bg_ul').click(function(){...}).appendTo(...);
```

или пользоваться выше предложенным методом `live`, который может вешать события на динамические элементы.

Comment: $('< ul>').attr('class','bg_ul').click(function(){...}).appendTo(...);

что то не получается
$('< ul>').attr('class','bg_ul').click(function(){что писать сюда}).appendTo(а сюда);
пробовал так не получился

$('< ul>').attr('class','bg_ul').click(function(){}).appendTo('<li value="'+pred_id+'">'+pred_name+'</li>');

Comment: Обратите внимание, что в скобках выбора UL присутствует лишний пробел (без него форматер кода сайта портит код). 
В тело функци (function(){}) пишите, то, что у вас и было записано по событию на клик.
appendTo() добавляет всю выборку перед ней к тому контейнеру, который будет у нее в скобках, т.е. $('#content').appendTo('#container') добавит контейнер id="content" к контейнеру id="container", на сайте хоршо описана эта функция и примеров валом http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/